# Column width doesn't go below fixed size

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

I have the following table:

[image]

created with the following code:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\scriptsize 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{b{0.18\linewidth}|b{0.05\linewidth}|b{0.2\linewidth}|b{0.2\linewidth}|b{0.2\linewidth}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{M}{Interviewee} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Party} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Date} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Position} & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Interviewer}  \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(r){3-3} \cmidrule(r){4-4}  \cmidrule(r){5-5} 
Ana Gomes & PS & December 6, 2013  & MEP since 2004 & Teste \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

My problem is that I want to make the second column with a smaller width. I'm setting `0.05\linewidth` to define the width but for some reason it doesn't go bellow `0.1\linewidth`

Comment: Please tell us how the `M` column type is set up.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I completely forgot I had column type. It is set as `\newcolumntype{M}{>{\scriptsize\arraybackslash}p{2.2cm}}
`.

Comment: You wrote, "I want to [reduce the width of] the second column..." Since you're assigning a fixed width of `2.2cm` to all column header cells, the width of the 2nd column can't be less than `2.2cm`.

Comment: why are you using fixed widths at all, rather than simply `l` ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment, with its width set to `\textwidth`, and that you use the `l` column type for the second column. That way, the 2nd column will have minimum width. Use a modified form of the `X` column for the other 4 columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}} % to emulate the OP's setup
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Y l YYY @{}}
\toprule
Interviewee & Party & Date & Position & Interviewer  \\
\midrule
Ana Gomes & PS & December 6, 2013  & MEP since 2004 & Teste \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```